# Unmet peer dependencies Upgrading to Angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, yeoman, package.json

I started with the [fountain yeoman generator](http://fountainjs.io/)

which gave me a nice angular 2 stub, but now Angular is on version 4

http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

So I used the upgrade instructions

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

This worked but I get these warnings:

`` +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-core@^6.0.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.3.3
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.8 ``

Do these matter and how to fix?

edit: in the `package.json` I have this (no babel-core):

```
"dependencies": { ...
  "zone.js": "^0.7.7" ...
"devDependencies": { ...
  "webpack": "^2.2.1",
```

Comment: what versions of babel-core, webpack, and zone.js do you have installed?

Comment: @pixelbits - just added that info

Comment: You should install/upgrade the PEER dependencies. `npm update zone.js webpack`  `npm install babel-core`

Comment: Thanks @pixelbits - I just tried those two commands. The first one seemed to work (although the package.json file is unchanged) but the second command still warns about the unmet dependancies for webpack@2.3.3 and zone.js@0.7.8

Comment: @ErichBSchulz warnings happen because npm does not know how to handle `peerDependencies`. For example, if I run `npm i -g typescript` and _then_ `npm i -g tslint`. I get a missing peer warning on the second one, even though the warning is erroneous because they were not installed via a single install command. **npm is dumb as a brick**.